# Selenium C# InPrivate Mode Internet Explorer

Tags: c#, selenium, internet-explorer-11, incognito-mode

I'm trying to launch IE11 on InPrivate mode when running my automated tests using Selenium C#. Found the options to do it but I can't seem to make mine work with these line of codes.

```
        InternetExplorerOptions options = new InternetExplorerOptions();
        options.ForceCreateProcessApi = true;
        options.BrowserCommandLineArguments = "-private";

        IWebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(options);
        return driver;
```

The driver opens as I can see it on task manager, but then IE does not open. If I remove options though inside the InternetExplorerDriver, it works totally fine. So there's something wrong with options. Would you have any idea about this?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not able to understand here "If I remove options though inside the InternetExplorerDriver, it works totally fine. ". What you're trying to remove ?

Comment: I mean if I just do
new InternetExplorerDriver();

instead of
new InternetExplorerDriver(options);

The options part causes a disconnect, can't find the issue though since it seems just sound.

Comment: Does your code throws any error ?

Comment: try this setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.IE_SWITCHES, "-private");

Comment: @mosaad, I think you are suggesting Java code. it does not work that way on C#

Comment: @MuralidharanDeenathayalan nothing useful on error msg/log, IE just does not launch and it times out

Comment: Are you able to open the IE in private mode ? Do you have enough permission to launch IE in private mode? Can you please share, selenium version, IE version, IE driver version and OS version for futher investigations?

Answer (score 2):

Quite an old topic, but in case someone still happens to need it... I stumbled upon a similar issue.

Check if you are using the 32-bit IE driver. I found out the hard way that `options.ForceCreateProcessApi = true;`
will cause this driver to timeout, at least for the versions I have tested (3.4.0 - 3.8.0). So far, I haven't managed to get private mode working for 32-bit in this setting.

For now, i use this as a work-around:

```
options.EnsureCleanSession = true;
```

This slows the tests down a lot, but at least it clears the cache.